# MariaDB Dynamic Columns integration in Java

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, mariadb

I am working on Proof of concept regarding the integration of MariaDB Dynamic column concept with Java. So the problem is the column will be in BLOB and the data will be stored in key - value pairs. Currently when byte[] is returned from the database doesnot have any JSON object format or any separators. So its very hard to parse the data and find the value for a key. This can be done using Native queries in Java. But how to retrieve data using JPA/Hibernate or will they support Dynamic columns? 
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to retrieve the data as COLUMN_JSON(dyncol)? Read more about it here: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/column_json/