# Mariadb dynamic columns using hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, nhibernate-mapping, mariadb

How to implement mariadb dynamic columns concept using hibernate mappings?

I have configured the mariadb in the my project but not clear to implement hibernate tables and data insertion into it and fetching data using criteria

Comment: yes, I'm stuck in the same challenge. here's another article asking the similar thing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28297059/mariadb-dynamic-columns-integration-in-java/28299820